# Adding the "Share" button for "Other answers" in review queues

Tags: script, review

This is a basic userscript which adds the Share link under answers in the review queues. It is based on [my own request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363704/add-the-share-button-to-other-answers-in-review-queues) from long ago.

It is intended to add the link to the "Other answers" tab in the answer queues, but as a side effect works in all queues:

[image]

There's a [GitHub page](https://github.com/tomerkal/Share-link-adder) and you can simply use [this link](https://github.com/tomerkal/Share-link-adder/raw/main/share_adder.user.js) to install (tested only with Tampermonkey and limited browsers).